# Tor trying to connect to a deleted bridge

Tags: configuration, torsocks, debian

I noticed some old bridges and deleted them. Tor still tries to connect to them.

Is there any place that tor reaches the bridge beside `etc/tor/torrc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for other files containing tor configuration data.

Having a look at the [manual](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en):

> ### -f *FILE*
>
> Specify a new configuration file to contain further Tor configuration options OR pass - to make Tor read its configuration from standard input. (Default: @CONFDIR@/torrc, or $HOME/.torrc if that file is not found)

It seems there may exist another file located in your home directory (`$HOME/.torrc`) which could contain the faulty configuration you wish to eliminate.

If you can't find this file, try searching for other files containing `torrc` in their name : )